# Are there other formalisms apart from Newtonian, Lagrangian and Hamiltonian?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

Or will there be?

In Newtonian formalism, we appoint a potential, then write newton's eq. which is equivolent to a initial value problem.

In Lagrangian formalism, we appoint a Lagrangian, then write Lagrangian eq.

In Hamiltonian formalism, we appoint a Hamiltonian, then write Hamilton-Jacobi eq.

Are other reasonable mechanisms that can generate dynamical systems?

Comment: See, e.g.,  the book "The  Variational Principles of Mechanics" by Lanczos, 
 https://books.google.fr/books/about/The_Variational_Principles_of_Mechanics.html?id=ZWoYYr8wk2IC&redir_esc=y